# Switch positions in array

Tags: c#, arrays

There are N operations to move an element of the string to the first position. Each move is specified on a line where the index of the item to be moved to the first position is entered. All other elements of the string remain in the same order.
For example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 - array
2 1 5 - indexes
```

The expected results:
6 2 1 3 4 5.
I'm not sure how can I use the temp variable to solve this problem. I've tried something like this:

```
static void MoveFirst(int[] values, int index)        
{
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                
                if (values[i] == index)
                {
                    int temp = values[i];
                    values[i] = values[i+1];
                    values[i + 1] = temp;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what issue you're having, or what problem you're trying to solve. I see a potential OutOfRange exception in your code. Can you [edit] your post with a [mre]?

Comment: I also do not see how your description matches the expected outcome. I would have expected `6 1 3 2 4 5` based on the initial data and inputs 2 , 1 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

The text of the problem does not quite match your code and parameters. But if you rely on what you described, you need to shift everything to the left by 1, remembering the element beforehand. You'll get something like this

```
static void MoveFirst(int[] values, int index)        
{
    int tmp = values[index];
    for (int i = index; i < values.Length; i--)
    {
        values[i] = values[i-1]
    }
    values[0] = tmp;
}
```